# Scala: Partition a listbuffer[List[String]] on first element in list

Tags: scala, collections, partitioning

I have a `ListBuffer[List[String]]` that contains :

```
List(1,"a",1)
List(1,"b",2)
List(2,"b",1)
List(2,"c",2)
List(2,"d",3)
List(3,"e",1)
List(3,"f",2)
```

I want to partition the `ListBuffer` depending on the first element, so all the lists that starts with 1 will be separated from 2, and so forth.

What I have now:

```
var feed = new ListBuffer[List[String]]()
val numberOfFeeds=feed.map(a => a.head).distinct.length
for(i<-1 to numberOfFeeds) {
  val k = feed.partition(x => x.head.toInt==i)
  println(k+"\r\n--------------------------------\r\n")
}
```

Comment: @Dima: please note the edit, I skipped the part where I fill the ListBuffer since the values are up top.

Comment: What do mean by "partition"? Do you want a `Map[String,List[String]]`, or a large tuple `(List[String],List[String],...)`, or something else?

Comment: Actually I needed a ListBufer[ListBuffer[List[String]]] which seems the answer provided by @ka4eli provides, I'm checking right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val result: Iterable[Listbuffer[List[Any]]] = listbuffer.groupBy(_.head).values`

In your case result will have 3 listbuffers in it, each with lists which have  the same first elements.

Or, if you want to preserve ordering:

`val result = listbuffer.groupBy(_.head).toList.sortBy(_._1.asInstanceOf[Int]).map(_._2)`

Here we have to use type casting `asInstanceOf` because list with elements is of type `List[Any]` and `sortBy` needs an instance of `Ordering[Any]` which it can't find. It looks clumsy, so I suggest you to use tuples or case classes instead of `List[T]` if you know exactly how many elements they will have.

```
val l = ListBuffer(
  (1, "a", 1),
  (1, "b", 2),
  (2, "b", 1),
  (2, "c", 2),
  (2, "d", 3),
  (3, "e", 1),
  (3, "f", 2))

l.groupBy(_._1).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
```

Comment: :I have a question, by using the groupby the order of elements have changed, is that expected?

Comment: There is nothing about preserving ordering in `groupBy` docs. Updated my answer to preserve ordering.